# why isn't this code working? [below is a pseudo code in C]

Tags: c, openmp

Below is a pseudo code in C. parallelized using OpenMP. What is wrong in the parallel OpenMP code that will prevent it from producing correct result  like  the serial code  and  how  will  you correct that?

```
void ccode (float a[], float b[], float c[], int n) {

float x, y ; int i;

#pragma omp parallel for shared (a,b,c,n,x,y) private i

for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){

    x = a[i] - b[i] ; 
    y = b[i] + a[i] ;
    c[i] = x * y ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is

```
x = a[i] - b[i] ;
y = b[i] + a[i] ;
```

where both `x` and `y` should be declared `private`, since each thread should be using its own pair of `x` and `y`.